# Using IF statement in MySQL to update or insert without Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it somehow possible to use an IF statement in MySQL to either update or insert a record into a table, without having to do it within a stored procedure ?

Given the nature of my setup, I cannot use Stored Procedures at this time, which is why I ask ..

Basically this is what I'm trying to do:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ........)
THEN
    INSERT ......
ELSE
    UPDATE ......
END IF
```

Here is my code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute`
    WHERE PRODUCT_ID = (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE NAME = 'PRODUCT_NAME_HERE')
    AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `oc_attribute_description` WHERE NAME='ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE')
)
THEN
    INSERT INTO `oc_product_attribute`
    VALUES
    (
    SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE NAME = 'PRODUCT_NAME_HERE',
    SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `oc_attribute_description` WHERE NAME='ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE',
    1,
    'XYZ'
    )
ELSE
    UPDATE `oc_product_attribute`
    SET TEXT = 'ABC'
    WHERE PRODUCT_ID = (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE NAME = 'PRODUCT_NAME_HERE')
    AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `oc_attribute_description` WHERE NAME='ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE')
END IF
```

I get this error with the above:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `oc_product_attribute` WHERE PRODUCT_ID = (SELE' at line 1
```

Note that I need to do the above in exactly ONE statement. I cannot span to multiple statements to achieve the above functionality .. Also no Stored Procedures :)

***Solved:***

As pointed out by Gordon, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is what I needed. Here is the final statement which works:

```
INSERT INTO `oc_product_attribute`
VALUES
(
(SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE NAME = 'PRODUCT_NAME_HERE'),
(SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `oc_attribute_description` WHERE NAME='ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE'),
1,
'XYZ'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TEXT='ABC';
```

But this assumes that the table has either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on it, or both.

Comment: . . You probably want `insert ... on duplicate key update` syntax.  Check this out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has special functionality on this situation. It's called `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. What it does is it tries to `INSERT` a record but if it already exists, it will just `UPDATE` it. '

In order to have this functionality working, you need to have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the table. Based on your example, I can see that you are checking on the two columns for its existence. If you already have a `PRIMARY KEY`, you can just add a `UNIQUE` constraint on both columns.

```
ALTER TABLE oc_product_attribute 
      ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(PRODUCT_ID, ATTRIBUTE_ID)
```

Once it has been executed, you can now use `INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO oc_product_attribute (PRODUCT_ID, ATTRIBUTE_ID, OtherCol, TEXT)
SELECT  MAX(PRODUCT_ID), MAX(ATTRIBUTE_ID), 1, 'XYZ'
FROM
        (
            SELECT  PRODUCT_ID, NULL ATTRIBUTE_ID 
            FROM    oc_product_description 
            WHERE   NAME = 'PRODUCT_NAME_HERE'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  NULL PRODUCT_ID, ATTRIBUTE_ID 
            FROM    oc_attribute_description 
            WHERE   NAME='ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE'
        ) x
ON  DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TEXT = 'ABC'

-- change OtherCol to the name of your column which you want to insert 1
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Marked yours as the answer, but Gordon told me first actually :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't have a way to only update if some other condition is met. For example if I want to update only if the current time is greater than an expiration column.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Gordon, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is what I needed. Here is the final statement which works:

```
INSERT INTO `oc_product_attribute`
VALUES
(
(SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE NAME = 'PRODUCT_NAME_HERE'),
(SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM `oc_attribute_description` WHERE NAME='ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE'),
1,
'XYZ'
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TEXT='ABC';
```

But this assumes that the table has either `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on it, or both.