# select from view -> update OR insert into table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select data from a mysql-view which collects and joins data from "federated"-tables.
This data should be inserted into a table which looks very similar to the view.

an example would be:

table where data needs to be inserted or updated:

### insertTable

```
+----+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | foreignId | data | foreignData |
+----+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | a         |  111 | aaa         |
|  2 | b         |  222 | bbb         |
+----+-----------+------+-------------+
```

the view where the data comes from:

### dataView

```
+-----------+-------------+
| foreignId | foreignData |
+-----------+-------------+
| a         | AAA         |
| b         | BBB         |
| c         | CCC         |
+-----------+-------------+
```

### insertTable

```
+----+-----------+------+-------------+
| id | foreignId | data | foreignData |
+----+-----------+------+-------------+
|  1 | a         |  111 | AAA         |
|  2 | b         |  222 | BBB         |
|  3 | b         |      | CCC         |
+----+-----------+------+-------------+
```

and at this point i think i need a stored procedure which does following written in pseudo code

```
$result = SELECT * FROM dataView;
  foreach $result as $row {
    if(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserTable WHERE foreignId=$row[foreignId]>0)
      UPDATE insertView SET foreignData = $row[foreignData] WHERE foreignId=$row[foreignId];
    else
      INSERT INTO insertView (id, foreignId, foreignData) VALUES (null,$row[foreignId],$row[foreignData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) query.

```
REPLACE INTO insertView (id, foreignId, foreignData) VALUES (null,$row[foreignId],$row[foreignData];
```

From mysql documentation

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See
>   Section 13.2.5, “INSERT Syntax”.

**PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index not specified it will insert a new row.**

So no need to SELECT checking.

Comment: replace wouldn't do the trick because of the data column, it would be lost? i found something on stackoverflow: [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16636203/1337131) maybe this is the right solution, i'll have a try

Comment: Ya that also do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

The magic which is ideal for this problem was **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

In my example the solution would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO insertTable
(
    `foreignId`,
    `foreignData`
)
SELECT 
    `dataView`.`foreignId`,
    `dataView`.`foreignData`
FROM
    `dataView`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `foreignId` = `dataView`.`foreignId`,
    `foreignData` = `dataView`.`foreignData`;
```